# PHP Apache print is suspended in server side if client just opens connection

Tags: php, apache

In server side I have script file test_print.php:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

file_put_contents("/home/tmp/debug.txt", "Test\n", FILE_APPEND);
$s_long_string = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $s_long_string .= "abcrc{$i}";
}

echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;
echo $s_long_string;

file_put_contents("/home/tmp/debug.txt", "Test2\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

And I have client script test.php:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('http://localhost/test_print.php', 'r');
?>
```

If I execute script test.php, then I can see that second line in file /home/tmp/debug.txt is not added. PHP code is suspended after first print and it waits for client to request content. If content is requested, then all PHP is executed, but if not then this PHP file is not fully executed.
Problem is that, if in client script is added sleep function, then PHP file is not fully executed and it waits for client action and therefore if there is some kind of database connection then it is not freed up.
I looked for some kind of parameter but I didn't find anything about it. I can repeat this strange behavior on Windows and on Ubuntu.
It is not related with Buffer cache, because in this situation server side script is suspended not output.

Is somebody faced this kind of Apache + PHP behavior and how could it be avoided? To my understanding when rendering PHP simble web page, then PHP script should be always executed fully not partially.

Comment: do you mean to `file_get_contents` on test_print.php? because I assume fopen-ing and reading it chunk wise (may) will block since what else should happen if you produce faster than you consume ?

Comment: Why do you want to add `sleep()` in client? If you are worried that it will consume 100% CPU then worry no more, it will block in read until some bytes are available.

Comment: I am not worried about client script, which can have sleep, but that in server side this script is not fully executed and after first print PHP waits for client to fetch next portion. In that way if I add sleep in client side, in server side PHP process waits for another fetch from client.